# What happens if your question is flagged as a duplicate and the question isn't answered on either page?

Tags: discussion

I had a question, and it was flagged as a duplicate of another question on th same topic but was a slightly different question, The answer wasn't on the other page and no one that didn't already answer the question would answer it.

Comment: Please provide a link to the question(s) you're referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question can be a duplicate even if it doesn't have an answer that entirely fits the specific case. Unfortunately, we can't force people to answer questions - if the answers already given don't help you, there's nothing that we can do to make someone give an answer that suits your specific situation.

Without the specific question in front of me, I am not sure specifically what you didn't get answered in the duplicate, but here are some things you can do to encourage people to perhaps help you out.

First, you can leave a comment on the question or on any of the answers asking for clarification of something you don't understand, or asking for information specific to what you want to know. Keep in mind that this might still not get you anything, if people don't know the information, aren't around, don't want to update their answer, etc.

You can also put a bounty on the question that is still open (aka not on hold). If you choose the "Improve details" bounty reasons, you can put in information related to your specific query in the custom comment box that will appear, and perhaps that will also encourage someone to answer/update an answer to reflect your concerns.

Keep in mind, however, that there might not be an answer, or that people might not answer specifically to what you want.

Comment: I thought you actually couldn't flag things as duplicates anymore unless the thing you're trying to dupe to had at upvoted answer.

Comment: I should clarify that. I meant more that it might not have an answer that the poster wanted.

Comment: I've said it before, and I'll say it again, this remains a moderate issue. If neither question has an answer, I still think they should *not* be flagged as duplicates.